# Create a counter based on days of the week, Fri-Mon treated as a bucket

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Today/Getdate is always going to be the starting date. A counter starts at 0; let's call it TheResult. If the day is Friday/Saturday/Sunday/Monday, then they all receive the same number in the counting process. The accrual picks back up on Tuesday.

| TheDate | TheDayName | TheResult |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-07 | Tuesday | 0 |
| 2022-06-08 | Wednesday | 1 |
| 2022-06-09 | Thursday | 2 |
| 2022-06-10 | Friday | 3 |
| 2022-06-11 | Saturday | 3 |
| 2022-06-12 | Sunday | 3 |
| 2022-06-13 | Monday | 3 |
| 2022-06-14 | Tuesday | 4 |
| 2022-06-15 | Wednesday | 5 |
| 2022-06-16 | Thursday | 6 |
| 2022-06-17 | Friday | 7 |
| 2022-06-18 | Saturday | 7 |
| 2022-06-19 | Sunday | 7 |
| 2022-06-20 | Monday | 7 |
| 2022-06-21 | Tuesday | 8 |

What would the sql code need to be to achieve the values in the TheResult column?

I'm not sure how to approach the problem because of the Fri-Mon bucket of days, so I have not made any progress. I've tried finding similar questions asked using Google, but it seems I'm searching for the wrong keywords to find the answer to my question.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you, lptr.

Comment: @Nicholas5280 … you could add **rows unbounded preceding** to the sum() over()

Comment: @lptr ... what about when the initial date falls on a Sat-Mon, then the counter starts at -1? How could the code be modified so that those days would start at 0 when any of them are the first date?